# Does DefaultMessageListenerContainer stop , shutdown close database connections?

Tags: spring, database, connection, spring-jms, sqlexception

I have a DefaultMessageListenerContainer which is processing a message from the queue.

While the message is being processed -- stop , shutdown methods are called on DefaultMessageListenerContainer. Does this close database connections?

Looks like it is closing the database connections and hence the message being processed is getting interrupted from completely processing.

I see these errors :

o.s.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory    : Error while extracting database name
Closed Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection

could these be because the DefaultMessageListenerContainer  was stopped and shutdown ?

---

My code is as follows . startStopContainer is where I am trying to stop and shutdown container. I want to shutdown container only if listener completed processing the current message. I added logic to figure out if listener completed processing .

Is the below logic the only way or is there a better way to figure out if listener completed processing. Please suggest. Thank you.

```
public class MyMessageConsumerFacade {
    
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(url);
        connectionFactory.setUserName(userName);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(password);

        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer() {
        
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        container.setDestinationName(queueName);
        container.setMessageListener(new MyJmsListener());      
        return container;
    }
}

public class MyJmsListener implements MessageListener { 
  public boolean onMessageCompleted; 
  public void onMessage(Message message) { 
     onMessageCompleted = false; 
     processMessage(message); 
     onMessageCompleted = true; 
  } 
} 

private String startStopContainer(ExecutionContext etk)  {
        String response = "success";
        
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = null;
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer myNewContainer = null;
        
        if (context == null) {
            context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyMessageConsumerFacade.class);
        }   

        if (myNewContainer == null) {
            myNewContainer = context.getBean(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.class);
        }

        MyCaseMessageJmsListener messageJmsListener = (MyCaseMessageJmsListener) myNewContainer.getMessageListener();
        

        if (!myNewContainer.isRunning()) {// container not running
            myNewContainer.start();
        }
        
        //due to some business logic we need to stop listener every 5 minutes, so sleep for 5 minutes and then stop
        try {
            Thread.sleep(300000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
                                
        if (myNewContainer.isRunning()) {
            myNewContainer.stop();
            
        }
        
        //Before shutting down container , make sure listener processed all msgs completely
        if(!messageJmsListener.isOnMessageCompleted) {      
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(messageJmsListener.isOnMessageCompleted) {
            myNewContainer.shutdown();
        }
        
        if (context != null) {
            context.destroy();          
        }
        
        return response;
    }
```

Is there a better way than this?

Answer (score 1):

No; the container knows nothing about JDBC or any connections thereto.

Stopping the container only stops the JMS consumer(s) the consumers from receiving messages; `shutDown()` on the container closes the consumer(s).

Something else is closing your JDBC connection.

Comment: The DefaultMessageListenerContainer starts. For some business logic, it needs to consume messages for 9 minutes and then needs to stop. In order to acheive this first we call DefaultMessageListenerContainer .start ,  then there is a Thread.sleep for 9 minutes and then the DefaultMessageListenerContainer stop and shutdown is called. .  Does the Thread.sleep for 9 minutes close DB connection somehow.

Comment: Does DefaultMessageListenerContainer stop and shutdown mean the onMessage method gets interruptted and stops ?

Comment: `>Does the Thread.sleep for 9 minutes close DB connection somehow` again, unless the code knows about the connection, it can't close it; simply sleeping a thread can't close a connection. `stop()` does not interrupt the receive thread, but `shutdown()` most likely will.

Comment: Sorry I didnt follow... when you say " shutdown() most likely will interrupt the receive thread" do you mean that if the onMessage method has not completed yet and during that time shutdown() is called , the onMessage method will terminate abruptly ?

Comment: `stop()` tells the consumer threads to not call the listener any more (after they process the current message, if any); the threads and consumers remain active. `destroy()` will interrupt the threads - they will only "terminate abruptly" if they are doing something that is interruptible - e.g. sleep, polling a queue, etc, etc. Generally, you should wait until your listeners exit after calling stop, before calling shutdown.

Comment: "Generally, you should wait until your listeners exit after calling stop, before calling shutdown."  How can we acheive this ?

Comment: Gary .. what method is available to check if listener exited .... that is to say ...  listener is done with the onMessage method so that shutdown can be called after that.

Comment: Add logic to your listeners to indicate whether they are active or not.

Comment: DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
container.setMessageListener(new MyJmsListener());                                                                                                                                                                                                        public class MyJmsListener implements MessageListener {
 public boolean onMessageCompleted;
 public void onMessage(Message message) {
  onMessageCompleted = false;
  processMessage(message);
  onMessageCompleted = true;
 }
} Is there a better way than this?

Comment: Don’t put code in comments. Hard to read. Edit the question instead and comment that you have done so.

Comment: I added the answer and added the code in there. Can you please take a look. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Gary ... edited the question. Could you pls check.

Comment: Something like that should work, but you should probably use a loop to wait for completion, or something more sophisticated, like a `Semaphore`.

Comment: Thankyou Gary. That worked but I wanted to know if JMS provides some built in api or methods to indicate that listener completed the current onMessage method , so we can use that as an indicator to call shutdown () instead of adding logic on our own.

Comment: No; there is no such API.

Comment: Thank ypu Gary . So what is the industry standard way of doing this. Does everyone generally have some logic built in to make sure current onMessage is processed before calling shutdown().

Comment: This is the first time I have heard of it being a problem; perhaps your listeners run for a long time or have some fragility when interrupted. It's rather weird that interrupting a listener thread would close a DB connection; must be something going on in your code.